# How to create thumbnail image in .net core? Using the help of IFormFile

Tags: c#, image-processing, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, thumbnails

I need to create a thumbnail image from the original image and need to save both images in the local folder. 
I am using html file control for uploading the image

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" asp-for="ImageName" name="ProductImage" id="ProductImage">
```

And by the time of form submission I am getting it as `IFromFile`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, ProductDTO product, IFormFile 
    ProductImage)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProductImage.CopyTo(ms);
            fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I have converted it to byte[] and passing it to one of my method for saving it. 
Here I need the thumbnail of the particular image

What I have tried so far is to add the `package Install-Package System.Drawing.Common -Version 4.5.1`

And created a method for converting the image

```
public string ErrMessage;

public bool ThumbnailCallback()
{
    return false;
}
public Image GetReducedImage(int Width, int Height, Image ResourceImage)
{
    try
    {
        Image ReducedImage;

        Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort callb = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

        ReducedImage = ResourceImage.GetThumbnailImage(Width, Height, callb, IntPtr.Zero);

        return ReducedImage;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrMessage = e.Message;
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the method which I created is accepting a type of `Image` So little confused here, not sure how can we do that with `byte[]`. Also I am not getting the image local path from the `IFileForm` so i cannot directly give the path too.

Can someone help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally got the answer

Installed  `System.Drawing.Common -Version 4.5.1` package

Open the package manager and run the below code for installing the package

> Install-Package System.Drawing.Common -Version 5.0.2

Then use the below code:

```
using System.Drawing;

var stream = ProductImage.OpenReadStream();

var newImage = GetReducedImage(32,32,stream);
newImage.Save("path+filename");

public Image GetReducedImage(int width, int height, Stream resourceImage)
{
    try
    {
        var image = Image.FromStream(resourceImage);
        var thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);

        return thumb;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Copying to a new memory stream is inefficient. Change your method to simply accept the `Stream` base type and pass in your file stream directly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Edited the answer, can you please have a look into that and let me know if any more changes are needed ?

Comment: You should wrap `OpenReadStream()` in a `using` block.

Comment: What if I want to just pass in only height or width and retain the images aspect ratio?

Comment: Beware that on Linux this library is using libgdiplus. And user can craft a file that will cause exterme memory usage on your server (for example a tiff with 1000 pages that will be only 100Kb )

Comment: Late to the party, but there are some serious remarks to be aware of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-6.0#remarks